# New to C# and OOP can someone explain this scope issue to me?

Tags: c#, list, scope

I haven't done much work with lists and OOP programming before so I am sorry if this is a simple formatting or visibility issue.

This is a method which is currently defined at the very top of my code

```
    namespace CrazyMaths
    {
        class Program
        {
            static int getMemory()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                int locationChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                int result = storeValues[locationChoice];
                return result;
            }
```

This is part of a separate method which calls getMemory()

```
            else if (tempNumber == "M")
            {
                result = getMemory();
                test = true;
            }
```

And this is the main block of code in which I declare my list.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> storeValues = new List<int>();
```

The name 'storeValues' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: storeValues  exists in the main function. not in the `getMemory` function

Comment: Or you will have to pass the POINTER to this List i.e. **storeValues** in the function getMemory( ___ ). And access or modify the storeValues in function using the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your method like below passing the `storeValues` list to the function `getMemory()`. Else it's obviously not accessible since `storeValues` is defined within `main()` method and so it's scope is bounded within the `main()` method only.

```
getMemory(storeValues)
```

So your `main()` should look like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> storeValues = new List<int>();
    getMemory(storeValues);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Why is it that I had to hand over that variable to each method and not with all the other variables that I use?

Comment: It's not clear what "other variables" you are referring to.  If they are defined at class level scope, then they are visible throughout the class.

Answer (score -1):

You should **declare** `storeValues` outside the Main function like this:

```
namespace CrazyMaths
    {
        class Program
        {
            private List<int> storeValues;

            static int getMemory()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                int locationChoice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                int result = storeValues[locationChoice];
                return result;
            }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        storeValues = new List<int>();
    }
```

Comment: `storeValues` in this code would be inaccessible in `Main` and `getMemory`. Look up the `static` keyword.